# Keep Flow types post webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack, flowtype

I want to add Flow to my current project I am working on. Everything works really great. However, I couldn't find a way of someway keep the types post build. I am using a monorepo structure and I have a lot of NPM modules. I would like to get an error if a module changes it's interface or it's exported functions/classes/types changes.

Any ideas/guidance is highly welcomed!

Thanks!

Comment: Does it not work if you just don't enable the `transform-flow-strip-types` babel plugin?

Comment: Like the description of the plugin **Strip all flow type annotations and declarations from your output code**. I don't want that. I would like to keep the types for when somebody uses my module and he/she also has flow integrated.

Comment: Could you clarify, are you bundling each individual module in your monorepo before publishing? Usually since only the end user of a module is bundling, it doesn't introduce an issue in the same way.

Comment: @AndreiCACIO I said if you *don't* enable that plugin. Ah but your problem is that whatever parser webpack uses doesn't support flow syntax?

Comment: @CameronMartin sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes, I can't disable that plugin because I need a runnable JS bundle after the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack bundles JS files into a single output file, it has no way do preserve Flow types in the output bundle.

If you want to preserve Flow logic for use *alongside* this bundle, the current best practice would be to include your original sourcecode as `.js.flow` files. [This blog post](https://medium.com/@ryyppy/shipping-flowtype-definitions-in-npm-packages-c987917efb65) elaborates on this approach, but the short version is, you'd use [`flow-copy-source`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-copy-source) to output a bunch of `.js.flow` files that match your original source code.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on others including your compiled bundle instead of the source files, you'll need to include a `.js.flow` file that provides all of the external type interfaces. [Here's the interface file for Immutable.js as an example](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/dist/immutable.js.flow).

Unless your library has some sort of build complexity that requires the distribution of its compiled assets, I would just rely on the consumers of your lib to compile and strip types on their own.